# SQL Server 2014 : using value from columns to generate a new value for new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this:

```
account   period01      period02      period03     period04
-----------------------------------------------------------
1111      null          null          null         null
1112      782           null          null         null
1113      null          null          null         345
1114      765           882           67           321
```

What I want to do is to get values from period1 through period04 and use the last value to code the value of accoutperiod.

So if value is from period1, then code it as 01, period2 as 02, period03 as 03 and period04 as 04.

In the end, the output should be like this

```
account   period01      period02      period03     period04  accoutperiod
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1111      null          null          null         null      null
1112      782           null          null         null      01
1113      null          null          null         345       04
1114      765           882           67           321       04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` like this.

```
SELECT account, period01, period02, period03, period04,
    CASE 
    WHEN period04 IS NOT NULL THEN '04'
    WHEN period03 IS NOT NULL THEN '03'
    WHEN period02 IS NOT NULL THEN '02'
    WHEN period01 IS NOT NULL THEN '01'
    ELSE NULL END as accoutperiod
From YourTable
```

Comment: What i understood for case statement is once a value matches expression, the CASE statement will execute the corresponding statements and not evaluate any further. So in this case if period1 till period 4 have value, the case statement will always retruned 01.

Comment: Simply rearrange the order of the `WHEN` statements, starting from period04 and ending with period01 - that should do the trick.

Comment: @jpw and Dan I agree . The wording in the question got me confused :)

Comment: can we use case statement as default value in create table statement ?

Comment: @user1902849 - you can create a computed column based on this `CASE` expression

Answer (score 0):

Even though @ughai answer's will help you get what you need but it fails to explain you how does 'CASE' statement works in sql.

> Hope my sample will guide you the way how does the case works with
>   multiple 'WHEN' statements.

Let us consider your table.

```
;WITH cte (account, period01, period02, period03, period04)
AS
(
    SELECT
        1111, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1112, 782, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1113, NULL, NULL, NULL, 345
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        1114, 765, 882, 67, 321
)
```

Below query is the common mistake everyone does to achieve our result.

```
SELECT 
    account,
    period01,
    period02,
    period03,
    period04,
    CASE 
        WHEN period01 IS NOT NULL THEN '01'
        WHEN period02 IS NOT NULL THEN '02'
        WHEN period03 IS NOT NULL THEN '03'
        WHEN period04 IS NOT NULL THEN '04'
        ELSE NULL END AS [accoutperiod]
FROM 
    cte
```

**The above query will Give you the following result:**

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════════╗
║ account ║ period01 ║ period02 ║ period03 ║ period04 ║ accoutperiod ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
║    1111 ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ NULL         ║
║    1112 ║ 782      ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ 01           ║
║    1113 ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ 345      ║ 04           ║
║    1114 ║ 765      ║ 882      ║ 67       ║ 321      ║ 01           ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════════╝
```

> Since first statement in the case has ***WHEN period01 IS NOT NULL
>   THEN '01'*** , So the statement get's success in the first attempt and
>   executed.

Now Let us Re-order the WHEN statement in reverse order.

```
SELECT
    account,
    period01,
    period02,
    period03,
    period04,
    CASE
        WHEN period04 IS NOT NULL THEN '04'
        WHEN period03 IS NOT NULL THEN '03'
        WHEN period02 IS NOT NULL THEN '02'
        WHEN period01 IS NOT NULL THEN '01'
        ELSE NULL END AS [accoutperiod]
FROM
    cte
```

**The above query will Give you the following result:**

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════════╗
║ account ║ period01 ║ period02 ║ period03 ║ period04 ║ accoutperiod ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
║    1111 ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ NULL         ║
║    1112 ║ 782      ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ 01           ║
║    1113 ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ NULL     ║ 345      ║ 04           ║
║    1114 ║ 765      ║ 882      ║ 67       ║ 321      ║ 04           ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════════╝
```